# Should I checkin binaries in src\packages also into source control?

Tags: .net, dll, nuget, package

Should I check-in the binaries that are in the packages folder of my solution also into TFS (or any source control server)?

Comment: The alternative would be "package restore": http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages - personally, committing binaries is tempting through simplicity and obviousness, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your project cannot work without them. Personally I distribute my dependencies as NuGets so I don't need to check them in TFS. When someone gets the latest version of the project, dependent NuGets are automatically retrieved from the respective locations.

Always think in terms of a recently reinstalled machine with Visual Studio and a developer gets the latest version of your project from TFS. This project should build without the developer needing to be doing anything. Just hit <kbd>Shift+F6</kbd>.

Comment: Now, I am confused. I don't understand the sentence, "Personally, I distribute my dependencies as NuGets so..." :-)

Comment: What are you confused about? You don't know what a NuGet is? You may read more about it here: http://docs.nuget.org/ For example the ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4 project templates use NuGets. When you create a new project in Visual Studio, the dependencies are fetched automatically from their respective locations.

Comment: Technically, NuGet can do package restore as an automatic build step, so it should still work - however, I tend to agree with you and go with the simplest option of just including them. It also reduces dependency on external networks etc.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I use in my projects. NuGet package restore. As far as the network dependency is concerned, well, we already have it because of TFS :-) Things are changing though with the introduction of Git in VS2012 SP1.

Comment: I've used NuGet (admittedly without a complete understanding of it) to install third-party packages that I needed in my project.

My question is: do I need to check-in third-party dlls that are in my local packages folder into TFS or may I just check-in the .nupkg and .nuspec files and the other devs will automatically have NuGet read these files and download the binaries from the Internet?

Comment: No, you don't need to check-in the binaries from the packages folder. You don't even need to check-in the nupkg and nuspec files from this folder if you use package restore: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages Only the `packages/repositories.xml` file could be version controlled. The packages will be downloaded from the internet (or a custom location) if you enable package restore.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. That's what I needed to know. That link was also very useful. Thanks @DarinDimitrov.